# Oxyplot. Построение графика по точкам

Tags: c#, oxyplot

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в OxyPlot (Windows Forms C#) построить график по точкам. Плюс нужно, чтоб на одном графике отображался график построенный по точкам и там же построенный по функции.